# Error when adding UIViewController to a UITabBarController in a Master-Detail application

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I would like to create a TabBarController in the Master view within a SplitViewController. I created my Storyboard as followed, adding a NavigationController to the Master view, with a TabBarController, having 2 UIViewControllers. [image]
However, this running this results in the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'Ddf-gp-fiE-view-y9r-Rz-gil''

When I change the 2 UIViewControllers to NavigationControllers, the exact same Storyboard runs fine.

What am I doing wrong here?